# Running ajax query after validation

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, validation

I have an ajax insert script and a validation script.

But the insert script is always working, so even if the validation sends a message that some fields are wrong, it still uploads the data.

How do I change my code so that the insert query only runs after the validation?

My code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
<div id="wrap">
<table>
<td>
    <form name="form">
        <tr>
        <p class="names">Voornaam:</p> <p><input type="text" name="voornaam" id="voornaam"></p>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <p class="names">Achternaam:</p> <p><input type="text" name="achternaam" id="achternaam"></p>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <p class="names">Telefoonnummer:</p> <p><input type="text" name="telefoonnummer" id="telefoonnummer"></p>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <p class="names">Emailadres:</p> <p><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></p>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <input class="knop" type="submit" name="insert" value="Opsturen" id="insert">
        </tr>
    </form>
</td>
</table>
<br>
<div id="berichten">

</div>

<script>
var validator = new FormValidator('form', [{
    name: 'voornaam',
    display: 'Voornaam',    
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'achternaam',
    display: 'achternaam', 
    rules: 'required'
},{
    name: 'telefoonnummer',
    display: 'telefoon', 
    rules: 'required|numeric'
},{
    name: 'email',
    display: 'email', 
    rules: 'required|valid_email'
}], function(errors, event) {
    var berichten = document.getElementById('berichten');

    berichten.innerHTML = '';

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0, l = errors.length; i < l; i++) {
            berichten.innerHTML += errors[i].message + '<br>';
        }

    }

});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#insert').click(function(){
            var voornaam = $('#voornaam').val();
            var achternaam = $('#achternaam').val();
            var telefoonnummer = $('#telefoonnummer').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();

            $.post('action.php',{action: "button", voornaam:voornaam, achternaam:achternaam, telefoonnummer:telefoonnummer, email:email},function(res){
                $('#result').html(res);
            });
            document.getElementById('berichten').innerHTML = 'Verstuurd!';        
        });
    });
</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is validation result? You should `return true / false` based on the validation result in ajax result.

Comment: It uses the validation.js script it just checks if the right data was inserted, I don't think there isa true/false line. They both work btw, but if I change the input type="button" to input type="submit" the validation stops working.

Comment: your jquery should listen for the form submit instead of the button click

Comment: But when I use the form submit, the page reloads, and I don't want it to reload.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be sending the ajax call in the [FormValidator](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/) callback if there are no errors.

```
function(errors, event) {
    var berichten = document.getElementById('berichten');

    berichten.innerHTML = '';

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0, l = errors.length; i < l; i++) {
            berichten.innerHTML += errors[i].message + '<br>';
        }

    } else {
        var voornaam = $('#voornaam').val();
        var achternaam = $('#achternaam').val();
        var telefoonnummer = $('#telefoonnummer').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();

        $.post('action.php',{action: "button", voornaam:voornaam, achternaam:achternaam, telefoonnummer:telefoonnummer, email:email},function(res){
            $('#result').html(res);
        });
        document.getElementById('berichten').innerHTML = 'Verstuurd!';   
    }
}
```

Comment: That submits the form, but doesn't add anything to the database. It also reloads the page, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/

Before formValidator add is_valid = true :

```
var is_valid = true;
var validator = new FormValidator.....
```

In event error add is_valid = false if length > 0 :

```
function(errors, event) {

    var berichten = document.getElementById('berichten');

    berichten.innerHTML = '';

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        is_valid  = false;
    }
```

Finally :

```
$('#insert').click(function(){
            if(is_valid){
               // is valid, do code here
            }      
        });
```

Comment: It doesn't insert anything, I see what you want to do, but somehow it isn't working.